# Disable notifications of some emails

Tags: notifications, gmail, email, 6.0-marshmallow

I daily receive many emails. I need a better control of emails. I want to disable notifications of some emails. A notification means for me that my phone vibrates and my smart watch vibrates. To filter those messages out of my inbox is not a possibility because I want to review them later. I think smartly disabling notifications of some emails would be great. Sometimes, I receive 30 emails in a row from one sender, for instance, what I do not want i.e. 30 vibrations in your phone and/or smart watch. I would like to have a feature that:

- disables notification for 3 hours if more than 2 emails received in one hour from one sender; and
- disable notifications for 3 hours if two emails received in 5 seconds from one sender.

How can you disable notifications of some emails in Android 6.0?

Comment: Tried Tasker and related apps? IFTTT maybe worth a try. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: You could review which labels you want notifications for.

Comment: @rds What do you mean by labels? I would like to have the feature in all incoming emails behaving as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the plugin *[Do Not Disturb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabooze.buzzoff)* and its *Now* mode more robust than *[eNotify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hermes.enotify)* because it is will disable all notifications of all applications by one button. However, it cannot do it for some applications only. I think *eNotify* could work for that but do not like its cost, its appearance, ... Its userbase is too small to get my trust.

Comment: @beeshyams I did a small edit. Please, feel free to contribute too. It is community wiki.

Comment: Sure will do when I can add. Thanks for wiki. As requested, please link the apps too